# Problem with ajax p:Calendar PrimeFaces 6.1

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

(JSF 1.2 and PrimeFaces 6.1)

I have a problem with the p: calendar tag, the problem occurs when selecting the calendar date, I don't see any action.

XHTML:

```
<p:calendar id="fechaPriseEnCharge" size="12" maxlength="10" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" mask="true" locale="es" 
               effect="scale" showOtherMonths="true" navigator="true" showButtonPanel="true"
               value="#{altaOrdCargaController.ordCargaCabecera.fechPriseEnCharge}">

               <p:ajax event="dateSelect" listener="#{altaOrdCargaController.dateChange}"/>

 </p:calendar>
```

JAVA:

```
public void dateChange(SelectEvent event) {
    ordCargaCabecera.setFechPriseEnCharge((Date) event.getObject());
    validarContrato(null);
}
```

Attached image of the calendar. What I do is select the day 27 (or any day), but it does nothing, does not set the value, or does the dateCahange method.

[Calendar, click not work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S8WgF.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [commandButton/commandLink/ajax action/listener method not invoked or input value not set/updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/commandbutton-commandlink-ajax-action-listener-method-not-invoked-or-input-value)

Comment: Your question is not good in multiple ways... There is no [mcve], PrimeFaces 6.1 cannot work with JSF 1.2. There is no attempt shown for research (see [ask]) or to generalize the problem, there is no attempt shown for debugging (javascript errors? Server side errors?